# Loading Sonata Admin Assets via Bower

Tags: bower, sonata-admin

I have never used Bower for package management and having managed to install on my localhost, the elements are not downloaded to the rightful folders.

How can I get around doing this? For past projects where I had less time, I copied files into /vendor folder and installed assets *runs and hides*.

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using bower to manage the asset dependencies of Sonata Admin then in the root of your project all you need are these two files:

.bowerrc

```
{
    "directory": "web/bundles/sonatacore/vendor"
}
```

bower.json

```
{
 "name": "my app",
 "version": "1.0",
 "license": "MIT",
 "dependencies": {
    "sonata-project-admin-bundle": "master"
 },
 "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
 ]
}
```

This way when you do a bower install, it will copy all of sonatas dependencies into the right folder.

The alternative is to integrate the bower install into a composer post install script that moves the files from bower_components into the right folders.

Hope that helps.